# I am using google sheets and receiving error Cannot find range or sheet for imported range?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am using google sheets and receiving error Cannot find range or sheet for imported range? Everything is correct and I reviewed all possible solutions. I have looked at all reviews to find the solution for the problem but no success. what is wrong or what do I have to do?

Comment: I thought that when you provide your current script and the situation of the Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue of `receiving error Cannot find range or sheet for imported range`, it will help users think of a solution.